# Why does Babel cause an error when used with PSPicture and LuaLaTeX?

Tags: errors, luatex, babel, ps

The MWE showed below only compiles if the line `\usepackage[greek,brazilian]{babel}` is removed.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\ifpdf\else
  \usepackage{pst-electricfield}
\fi

\usepackage[greek,brazilian]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-6,-6)(6,6)
  \psframe*[linecolor=lightgray!50](-6,-6)(6,6)
  \psgrid[subgriddiv=0,gridcolor=gray,griddots=10]
  \psElectricfield[Q={[1 0 0]},linecolor=black] 
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Here's an extract of the latex log for the error:

```
File: main-pics.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)

<use main-pics.pdf, page 1>
Package pdftex.def Info: main-pics.pdf, page1 used on input line 13.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 571.13235pt x 572.1361pt.

Overfull \hbox (241.13235pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 13--17
[][][] 
 []

[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}


Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!<./main-pics.pdf>] (./main.aux))

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 10093 strings out of 494688
```

Do you know why using Babel causes that error?

Comment: Your log-extract shows no error.

Comment: Well, you're right. Actually, there's no explicit acusation of error anywhere in the log file, but `Overleaf` prompts the message `compile error` and gives the option `open latex log`. Isn't that `overfull` considered an error? I guess it is the problem, but I can't solve it and don't know why it appears only if the `babel` package is included.

Comment: Overfull messages are no errors, but your document needs --shell-escape and so I doubt that you can compile it on overleaf.

Comment: do you need to use luatex, you could use latex or xetex and pstricks would work natively.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In my non-MWE document, I use also some features only allowed with luatex.

Comment: I get no compilation error using `lualatex -shell-escape` (texlive 2018)